# In React, Is there a difference between returning a function call, and JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
function Foo(props) {
  return <Bar someProp={true} />;
}
```

```
function Foo2(props) {
  return (Bar({ someProp: true });
}
```

Is there a difference between the two of them?

It works the same for me so I'm not sure what to expect...
am I missing something?

Comment: Hi. The main difference is just syntax. However, JSX is recommended for better readability and maintenance

Comment: @Johan - There's a much bigger difference than syntax. In `<Bar ... />`, the `Bar` function **isn't called** until/unless rendering happens, and is potentially called repeatedly to do repeated renders (if it's a function component, not a class component). In `Bar({...})`, it's called immediately (and only once).

Comment: The linked question doesn't answer the question entirely. I think here OP is asking if they can call a component as a function